# Using two columns from previous row to determine column value in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate a value for each row in a Pandas data frame by comparing two columns to the values of the same columns for the previous row. I was able to do this by using iloc, but it takes a really long time when applying it to over 100K rows.

I tried using lambda, but it seems that it only returns one row or one column at the time, so I can't use it to compare multiple columns and rows at the same time.

In this example, I subtract the value of 'b' for the previous row from the value of 'b' for the current row, but only if the value of 'a' is the same for both rows.

This is the code I've been using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b','b'],'b':[1,2,3,4,5]})

df['increase'] = 0
for row in range(len(df)):
    if row > 0:
        if df.iloc[row]['a'] == df.iloc[row - 1]['a']:
           df.iloc[row, 2] = df.iloc[row]['b'] - df.iloc[row - 1]['b']
```

is there a faster way to do the same calculation?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html): `df['a_prev'] = df['a'].shift(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can suing `groupby` +`diff`

```
df.groupby('a').b.diff().fillna(0)   
Out[193]: 
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

After assign it back

```
df['increase']=df.groupby('a').b.diff().fillna(0)
df
Out[198]: 
   a  b  increase
0  a  1       0.0
1  a  2       1.0
2  b  3       0.0
3  b  4       1.0
4  b  5       1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
df['increase'] = [0] + [(d - c) if a == b else 0 for a, b, c, d in \
                        zip(df.a, df.a[1:], df.b, df.b[1:])]
```

Some benchmarking vs [@Wen's pandonic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48713174/9209546):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b','b']*20000,'b':[1,2,3,4,5]*20000})

%timeit [0] + [(d - c) if a == b else 0 for a, b, c, d in zip(df.a, df.a[1:], df.b, df.b[1:])]
# 51.6 ms ± 898 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby('a').b.diff().fillna(0)
# 37.8 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```